# Mongoose Date.now time wrong

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my Mongoose schema I'm using Date.now to insert a user based on creation time. For some strange reason (unknown to me), the time is one hour behind. I'm thinking it's because I'm (GMT+1) but and my Express/Node/Mongo setup must be standard GMT time, or maybe not. Has anyone come across this before?

```
User = new Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    emailAddress: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: [true, 'Email address is required.']
    },
    uniqueURL: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Comment: `Date.now()` returns a timestamp, which is timezone-independent. How do you determine that it's an hour behind?

Comment: I checked inside Mongo.

Comment: Does MongoDB show a timezone in the results?

Comment: Here is what shows: "created" : ISODate("2016-05-19T14:39:09.999Z"),

Comment: And it's that timestamp that's an hour behind the "current" time? It's in UTC, which should be okay. When you retrieve it from Node it should be converted back to your current timezone.

Comment: I now see what you're saying. This works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/4/ thanks.